# How do I use hammerjs with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hammer.js

I am trying to using hammer js in ionic angular project.

I have imported hammermodule in my component's module:

```js
import { BrowserModule, HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
HammerModule,
//...
]})
```

And imported hammerjs inside the component as per docs. But no event is triggered.

```html
<div (swipeleft)="onswipe(i)">swipe me</div>
```

```js
onswipe(x){
console.log(x,'triggered')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HammerModule should be imported inside AppModule(not inside child modules).

You can import 'hammerjs' inside the components.